# How to know which group a user belongs to

Tags: python, django

I am developing an application that allows me to control the users that belong to a certain group, but I find a problem that I don't know how to do correctly, I currently have two groups that are day and night, but I have a problem, and that is that those groups They are validated to know which one they belong to and thus show only information from that group, but if I wanted to add more groups than I have, is there a way to know which group a user belongs to and so on to be able to validate the information that I show in templates, this is my model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    def get_full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def group_user(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.groups:
        if instance.groups == 'diurno':
            group = Group.objects.get(name='diurno')
            instance.groups.clear()
            instance.groups.add(group)
        else:
            group = Group.objects.get(name='nocturno')
            instance.groups.clear()
            instance.groups.add(group)
```

This is my view:

```
class CarListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = 'users:login'
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        group = self.request.user.groups.filter(
            name='diurno').exists()
        if group:
            return Car.objects.annotate(Count('partner')).order_by('-pk')
        else:
            user = User.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk).first()
            return Car.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instance.groups.all()` will give a `QuerySet` of groups the user belongs to. So you can check if the user belongs to the `administradores` with:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def group_user(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.groups:
        if instance.groups.filter(name='diurno').exists():
            group = Group.objects.get(name='diurno')
            instance.groups.clear()
            instance.groups.add(group)
        else:
            group = Group.objects.get(name='nocturno')
            instance.groups.clear()
            instance.groups.add(group)
```

By checking with `instance.groups == 'diurno'` that test is always `False`, and thus you will each time when you save a user object assign it to the `desarrolladores` group. By clearing however the groups, a user can never belong to multiple groups.

In your view you can slightly improve the readability with:

```
class CarListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Car
    login_url = 'users:login'
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        is_diurno = self.request.user.groups.filter(
            name='diurno'
        ).exists()
        if is_diurno:
            return qs.annotate(Count('partner')).order_by('-pk')
        else:
            return qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

I would however strongly advise *not* to use signals, but add logic to the views where your edit your user. Note that the `post_save` method will *not* run when you edit the groups of a user, only when you save the user itself. This thus means that at the moment when you *create* a user, it will *first* save the user (without any groups), and after that add the groups to the user. This makes the way signals work less predictable. Here if you thus create a user that belongs to the `diurno` group: that user will after the signals run belong to both the `diurno` group *and* the `nocturno` group.

Comment: If for example I have 20 groups, do I have to repeat the code 20 times?

Comment: @cosmosmulti: normally the idea is that you make views per permission. Each group has permissions. A person that thus does not belong to any group with the given permission, simply can not access that view. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization and the `PermissionsRequiredMixin`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin

Answer (score 2):

```py
# all groups a user belongs to
user.groups.all()

# check if a user belongs to a specific group, returns a boolean
user.groups.filter(name="NameOfYourGroup").exists()

# check if a user belongs to at least one group from a list, returns a boolean
user.groups.filter(name__in=['list','of','groups']).exists()
```

Comment: Excuse me, but the solution you have already used, what I would like to know is how can I know which group a user belongs to, because each group will have different permissions, then to validate which group a user belongs to I have to do the code for that way always and repeat it every time?

Comment: @cosmosmulti : you could do something like ```user.groups.filter(name__in=['list','of','groups']).exists()```